# After Pageload map will be display none but after button click it will be display block

Tags: google-maps, yii

I'm using Egmap Extension for map preview.The problem which i'm facing right now is when the page gets loaded map is hiden but after clicking display button map appears partially on the frame means in left corner some of the mappart is displayed.So to resolve this problem i was using map trigger code which is written below but its not working.

How should i implement this code in Egmap yii extension ?

```
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For yii Egmap extension it will be EGMap0 instead of map.So the code will be

```
   google.maps.event.trigger(EGMap0, 'resize');
```